# Loopback 4: Scheduled cron example using Loopback 4

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback, v4l2loopback

As I am very new with loopback 4 and Typescript, knowing that we have to  use custom booter to implement schedule tasks like Cron.

I require a code snippet which does that, i.e A custom booter class that implements Booter phases of configure, discover and load to Run a Cron

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this is the way to do it, but this is working for me.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Booting-an-Application.html#bootcomponent

Start with creating a component inside the project folder. I created `src\components\cron.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from "@loopback/core";
import { CronJob, CronCommand } from "cron"

export class CronJobsComponent implements Component {
    private cj: CronJob;
    constructor(){
        this.start()
    }

    async start(){
        this.cj = new CronJob('* * * * * *', this.showMessage)
        this.cj.start();
    }

    showMessage:CronCommand = async () => {
        console.log("inside cron jobs")
    }

}
```

Next import our component in the `application.ts` file

`import { CronJobsComponent } from './components'`

and register our new component inside the constructor

`this.component(CronJobsComponent);`

The corn job starts on application boot.

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cron

Hope this helps you.

Comment: For some reason i see "inside cron jobs" printing twice per job.  My CronJob runs every 10 seconds CronJob('*/10 * * * * * ', this.ShowMessage).  Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a cron endpoint.

http://localhost:3000/cron

You could then add a curl command to your crontab.

```
curl http://localhost:3000/cron
```

This method is a great way to handle seperation of concerns. If your api is a microservice running on kubernetes, you could call the cron endpoint using the `Cron` resource.

Just make sure that the endpoint is secure if your application is public.